# jqGrid sorting problem id name and index are different

Tags: javascript, xml, sorting, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid plugin retrieving data as xmlstring.
My problem is that sorting works only if in the colModel i set for the name property the same value of the index property.
Example with sorting working:

```
colModel:[
  {name:'F_CODE', index:'F_CODE', sortable:true, sorttype:'text'}
]
```

Example with sorting not working:

```
colModel:[
  {name:'FARM CODE', index:'F_CODE', sortable:true, sorttype:'text'}
]
```

I need to assign human readable names to the name property because I use them as columns headers in my grid2excel java code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You don't posted the full definition of the jqGrid which you use, but indirect from your question I suppose that you don't use [colNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) which defines the "human readable" column names. So you can either insert the parameters like

```
colNames: ['FARM CODE']
```

of use the additional [label](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) property:

```
colModel:[
    {name:'F_CODE', label: 'FARM CODE', index:'F_CODE'}
]
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, 
I use colNames but my Java code does not read it and I didn't want to change it because I prefer to work with javascript... At the end I decided to adjust the java excel export and now all is working fine.
Thanks anyway for the answer